# Using python for commercial web application development

Tags: python, web-applications, web-frameworks

We (there are 2 of us) are new to web application development and are trying to develop a web based application product targeted at medium sized businesses.

The following is a basic flow of the work flow of the application:

1. Collect data through file upload process (100K to 5 million records)
2. Collect control data from users through forms
3. Perform statistical analysis on the input data based on business rules
4. Generate reports and visualization graphs
5. Process (Edit, Encrypt, Redact etc…) the input file and generate output file.
6. The application has to support 50 to 100 users concurrently.
7. The application will be an intranet application and will not be available over the web.

We have decided to use PostgreSQL as our database.

We did some research on the web to find a suitable language to build our application. We are thinking about using Python as we have got some Python experience already.

However we couldn’t decide on the python web frameworks. Are there any serious drawbacks in using a 3rd party web framework for a project like ours?

We welcome suggestions about other languages/framework that would best suit this scenario.

This is our first post and if you need more details, do let us know.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question, yes you absolutely should use a 3rd party web framework. There's no use in reinventing the wheel.

The two Python web frameworks that I am familiar with are Pylons and Django. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681/pros-cons-of-django-vs-pylons) covers the pros and cons for using either. Based on your description I would recommend Django.

Comment: Our commercial web application is similar to this one.  We use Django.

Answer (score 1):

Django is awesome.

It is really easy to extend and is very well documented.  I highly recommend you check it out.

http://www.djangoproject.com/